# How to correct odd Japanese Maple growth pattern?

Tags: pruning, tree-care

I performed my first pruning of this tree last year, removing some lower branches and shortening the longest branch (growing towards the house) as I lost the middle leader naturally.  I pruned about 1/4 of the tree.  In that same growing season, the tree responded by shooting off quick branches from that same branch growing towards the house.  Now, in the second season, the ends of those shoots have developed these dense sections. The ends of these shoots have a lot of growth, but each has a bare one foot section that is starting to grow buds but create an odd shape to the tree.

Is there a reason or name for this type of behavior and how would I correct it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What time of year did you prune it? When you should prune varies depending on what you are trying to achieve, as trees respond differently to pruning in winter .vs. spring .vs. summer (you generally want to avoid pruning in fall, for most trees.)

Comment: I didn't prune in early spring or winter as I figured a maple would bleed. It must have been early summer. I was hoping these bare branches would fill in but they just focused more growth on those tips.

Comment: Tip pruning is almost always a very bad idea, as your experience kind of proves. Your best bet now is simply to cut that branch back to the trunk.

Comment: So if you lose a leader, and another leader is too long or or running in an undesired direction, there is no other recourse besides cutting it back to the trunk?

Comment: I see one big potential problem, the A/C unit. Many plants stress from being close to such devices. You might do better if you could put some sort of wind-break type thing between your tree and this device. However, you need to be sure it won't interfere with the functioning of the device.